# Running a GPU-trained XGBoost model on a CPU machine later

Tags: gpu, cpu, xgboost

I have trained and validated an XGBoost model on a GPU machine and pickled it. When I load the pickle and test on the same machine, it works perfectly. I get the multiclass `ROC_AUC` and the works. When testing on another machine, which only has CPUs to spare, I load the pickle, and as necessary, set:

```
xgboost_clf = xgboost_clf.set_params(predictor = 'cpu_predict')
xgboost_clf = xgboost_clf.set_params(tree_method = 'hist')
```

I run it:

```
Y_test_pred_xgboost = xgboost_clf.predict(X_test)
```

But all the results NOW belong to the first of my multiple classes. I would greatly appreciately the answer to the question: what have I still left out?

With kind regards, 
  Jaan :)

PS! Does not seems to pretain to this problem, which is a fixed issue. 
https://github.com/h2oai/h2o4gpu/issues/625

Comment: Did you find the answer of this question? 
I have a different issue : I am loading GPU based model on CPU, it is working fine in inferencing. But I would like to retrain the same model using its booster. It is throwing error.

Comment: Did not find a solution.